# Unable to debug Qt 5.8 application under MacOs 10.12 - app crashes with "lazy symbol binding failed"

Tags: c++, macos, qt, macos-sierra, qt5.8

Application build with "release" settings in QtCreator builds and runs fine.
Building / running the code with "debug" fails at startup of application with the following error on console and crash report.

Build Info:

```
Qt Creator 4.2.2
Based on Qt 5.8.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)
Erstellt am Apr 3 2017 04:09:42
Revision 991f5eb6a5
```

Console Output :

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN9QCFString9toQStringEPK10__CFString
  Referenced from: /Users/manuel/projects/rawstack/build-debug/app/rawstack.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
  Expected in: /Users/manuel/Qt/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore_debug

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN9QCFString9toQStringEPK10__CFString
  Referenced from: /Users/manuel/projects/rawstack/build-debug/app/rawstack.app/Contents/PlugIns/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib
  Expected in: /Users/manuel/Qt/5.8/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore_debug
```

Stack trace :

```
1   __abort_with_payload                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0x1001089ee    
2   abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal                                                                                                                                                                                                               0x10010843b    
3   abort_with_payload                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0x100108464    
4   dyld::halt(const char *)                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0x1000e3793    
5   dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader * *, unsigned long)                                                                                                                                                                                          0x1000e389e    
6   dyld_stub_binder                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0x7fffce62f282 
7   None                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0x1045f2008    
8   ___lldb_unnamed_symbol1006$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                       0x1044cba06    
9   ___lldb_unnamed_symbol24$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                         0x104489ef9    
10  ___lldb_unnamed_symbol5$$libqcocoa.dylib                                                                                                                                                                                                          0x10448888e    
11  QPlatformIntegrationPlugin::create(QString const&, QStringList const&, int&, char * *)                                                                                                                       qplatformintegrationplugin.cpp  64   0x1023aa358    
12  QPlatformIntegration * qLoadPlugin<QPlatformIntegration, QPlatformIntegrationPlugin, QStringList const&, int&, char * *&>(QFactoryLoader const *, QString const&, QStringList const&&&, int&&&, char * *&&&) qfactoryloader_p.h              101  0x1023a9877    
13  QPlatformIntegrationFactory::create(QString const&, QStringList const&, int&, char * *, QString const&)                                                                                                      qplatformintegrationfactory.cpp 71   0x1023a9122    
14  init_platform(QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, int&, char * *)                                                                                                                                qguiapplication.cpp             1115 0x1023b9b0b    
15  QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration()                                                                                                                                                          qguiapplication.cpp             1278 0x1023b9906    
16  QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher()                                                                                                                                                              qguiapplication.cpp             1295 0x1023ba33f    
17  QApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher()                                                                                                                                                                 qapplication.cpp                188  0x102bce165    
18  QCoreApplicationPrivate::init()                                                                                                                                                                              qcoreapplication.cpp            787  0x101dd2be5    
19  QGuiApplicationPrivate::init()                                                                                                                                                                               qguiapplication.cpp             1318 0x1023b71d5    
20  QApplicationPrivate::init()                                                                                                                                                                                  qapplication.cpp                568  0x102bce7af
```

Used compiler :

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

What could be the cause ? How to fix this ?

Comment: Make sure you check the checkbox that says "use debug framework" in the RUN settings of the project.

Comment: Checkbox "use debug framework" and option to add DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLIB_FRAMEWORK_PATH are selected.
Clean rebuild - still crashes with same error.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Sierra VM handy so I can't test that :(